# Updating First Line of Text File

Tags: vb.net

My program is essentially a small "bank account" that allows the users to write debits and credit to an account (a text file). Currently, my program will allow the user to do such things, and calculate the balance in a combo box index called "show balance". While this program will subtract debits from balance and add credits to balance, it is supposed to also be able to take an existing file, read the balance from it, save it, and so on.

My issue is while my program updates the balance when the file is open, it will not save the balance back to the program and then read the balance, show it in the "show balance" index, and then allow the user to continue to update it.

I've tried adding a StreamReader to read the balance from the file when the show balance index is selected, and then write the balance back to the file, but I cannot seem to make it work.
THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WANT: THE PROGRAM WILL CURRENTLY WRITE BOTH DEBITS AND CREDITS TO THE FILE, BUT I NEED A WAY OF "CONTROLLING" THE BALANCE WITHIN THE FILE. I NEED TO BE ABLE TO READ THE BALANCE IN THE SHOW BALANCE() SUB FROM THE FILE AND THEN BE ABLE TO ALSO CHANGE IT USING THE DEBITS AND CREDITS AND WRITE IT BACK TO THE FILE SO IT CAN BE USED AGAIN. CURRENTLY THE BALANCE IS SET DEFAULT TO 0, AND CAN ONLY BE MODIFIED WHILE THE PROGRAM IS OPEN, AND ONCE IT IS TERMINATED, AND REOPENED, THE BALANCE WILL STILL SHOW 0. THAT IS WHAT NEEDS FIXED.
 Below is my code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim tbDollar As String
    Dim tbMemo As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim creditAmount As String
    Dim debitAMount As String
    Dim Balance As Double
    Dim action As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "Mike Smith's Bank Account"
        Call LoadData()
        Call MainMenu()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cb1.SelectedIndexChanged
        action = Cb1.SelectedIndex
        If action = 0 Then
            Call SetUpCredit()
        ElseIf action = 1 Then
            Call SetUpDebit()
        ElseIf action = 2 Then
            Call ShowTransactions()
        ElseIf action = 3 Then
            Call ShowBalance()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btConfirm.Click
        If action = 0 Then
            Call ProcessCredit()
            Balance = Balance + Convert.ToDouble(tbDollar)
        ElseIf action = 1 Then
            Call ProcessDebit()
            Balance = Balance - Convert.ToDouble(tbDollar)
        End If
        Cb1.SelectedIndex = -1
        Tb1.Text = ""
        Tb2.Text = ""
        Lb4.Text = Convert.ToString(Balance)
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        ListBox1.Visible = False
        btConfirm.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainMenu()
        btConfirm.Visible = False
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        ListBox1.Visible = False
        Lb4.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadData()
        Dim FileFound = False
        Do Until FileFound = True
            fName = InputBox("Please enter your file path", "Enter your file path")
            If File.Exists(fName) Then
                FileFound = True
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("File not found!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetUpCredit()
        btConfirm.Visible = True
        Lb1.Visible = True
        Lb2.Visible = True
        Tb1.Visible = True
        Tb2.Visible = True
        ListBox1.Visible = False
        Lb4.Visible = False
        Lb1.Text = "Enter Credit Amount"
        Lb2.Text = "Enter a Memo"
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetUpDebit()
        btConfirm.Visible = True
        Lb1.Visible = True
        Lb2.Visible = True
        Tb1.Visible = True
        Tb2.Visible = True
        ListBox1.Visible = False
        Lb4.Visible = False
        Lb1.Text = "Enter Debit Amount"
        Lb2.Text = "Enter a Memo"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowTransactions()
        btConfirm.Visible = False
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        ListBox1.Visible = True
        Lb4.Visible = False
        Dim SRObject As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fName)
        Dim ftext As String

        Do While SRObject.Peek() <> -1
            ftext = SRObject.ReadLine()
            If ListBox1.Items.Contains(ftext) Then

            Else
                ListBox1.Items.Add(ftext)
            End If
        Loop

        SRObject.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowBalance()
        btConfirm.Visible = False
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        ListBox1.Visible = False
        Lb4.Visible = True
        Lb4.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(Balance)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessCredit()
        tbDollar = Tb1.Text
        tbMemo = Tb2.Text
        Dim SWObject As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fName, True)
        SWObject.WriteLine("Credit: " + tbDollar + ", " + tbMemo)
        MessageBox.Show("You credited " + tbDollar + " to your account!", "Success!")
        SWObject.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessDebit()
        tbDollar = Tb1.Text
        tbMemo = Tb2.Text
        Dim SWObject As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fName, True)
        SWObject.WriteLine("Debit: " + tbDollar + ", " + tbMemo)
        MessageBox.Show("You debited" + tbDollar + "to your account!", "Success!")
        SWObject.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tb1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Tb1.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then e.Handled = True
        If e.KeyChar = "," And Tb1.Text.IndexOf(",") = -1 Then e.Handled = False
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then e.Handled = False
        If e.KeyChar = "." And Tb1.Text.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then e.Handled = False
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then Tb2.Focus()
    End Sub
End Class


I believe there should be a streamreader in the show balance sub to read the first line of the file and save it as the balance, and then write the balance back to the user when it is updated, but i cannot seem to get it figured out. Any help would be appreciated.
```

Comment: To repeat some of the comments to a previous question, this is very broad and most of the code shown has nothing to do with the question.  Text files are not random access critters.  Read the data in at the start of the program and write it back out when exiting.

Comment: On another note, a 1 year member has has plenty of time to read [ask] and take the [tour] to understand how SO works.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]